# Is there a way to suppress WebRTC connections to keep power saving features active?

Tags: linux, power-management, kde, chromium, webrtc

I am using KDE on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. When viewing reputable news sites in Chromium, it appears the browser creates WebRTC connections in the background (without audio or video, so no permissions are requested). The KDE power saving widget displays the following message: `/usr/lib64/chromium/chromium is currently suppressing power management: WebRTC has active peer connections`

Is there a way to suppress these WebRTC connections? I find it rather distasteful that power saving is disabled on my computer when I am viewing what should be a static webpage.

This problem remains in version 71 of Chromium.

Comment: It probably web notifications. In "settings"/"Content Settings" set radio button to  "do not allow any site to show notifications"

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Chromium 56.0.2924 in KDE. There seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=612294) in Chromium's WebRTC implementation that causes `PowerSaveBlock` to stay activated even when there are no active `PeerConnections`. The issue should have been resolved for versions 57 and 58.

Comment: Problem remains in Chromium 58.

Comment: @mattm it was fixed for me with chromium upgrade from version 56.0.2924.87-1 to version 57.0.2987.98-1 back in March, and the problem hasn't reappeared since then